# How does the temperature of a liquid affect viscosity in mathematical terms?

Tags: temperature, viscosity

To clarify, how is the viscosity of a liquid related to its temperature. Does the coefficient change?

Edit: Sorry for the low effort question. Here's a more in-depth one:

So my confusion stems mainly from what viscosity is affected by and how is that represented in the various formulae.

I know of a viscosity coefficient. Is this something that is inherent to a liquid or is it variable and changes in response to other factors, namely temperature.

Is viscosity measured by the viscosity coefficient?

Secondly, how does the temperature affect viscosity? Does it alter the coefficient or is it a separate factor that affects viscosity?

Having read the Wikipedia article, I wasn't able to find a relation between viscosity and temperature in a model or formula, for *liquids*.

Lastly, the motivation behind this question, aside from simple curiosity and understanding, is that I am designing an experiment to investigate the factors that affect the fluid damping of an object in harmonic motion, as a high school project. I narrowed my two factors to analyse as viscosity and temperature. However, upon further reflection, I realised that the temperature must affect viscosity. Thus I had to choose temperature and the nature of the liquid as my two factors. The issue was that I wasn't sure if temperature affected the *coefficient* or viscosity *directly*. If it affected viscosity, then did the *nature of the liquid* affect the coefficient? If it affected the coefficient, then what did the nature of the liquid affect?

Note that by nature of the liquid I mean the liquid itself, like water or oil.

Comment: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Temperature_dependence_of_liquid_viscosity Check net before you ask at least check Wikipedia

Comment: I did check wikipedia. I didn't understand it

Comment: Well if you didn't understand the Wiki article, can you write up what it was about the article that you couldn't grasp? It would make the question go from appearing to be zero-effort (that is likely to be closed) to a decent question (that may not be closed).

Comment: Apologies for the low effort question. I had a hard time putting it into words. @KyleKanos . Hope it's better now.

Comment: Transport Phenomena by Bird, Stewart, and Lightfoot has a detailed discussion and quantitative treatment of the molecular mechanics regarding the effect of temperature on the viscosity of a liquid.

Comment: @ChesterMiller This is a book? Thanks for this I will take a look at it.

Comment: Yes.  A well-known textbook.

Answer (score 1):

I found this chart on google. It might answer several questions of yours. 
[image]

Edit: I found these formuals as well :

[image]

Comment: Thanks for this, but do you know if this is specific to a liquid? If so what liquid? And do you know the significance of the 0.0168?

Comment: It is for a type of engine  oil [link](http://www.viscopedia.com/viscosity-tables/substances/engine-oil/)
And no, unfortunately I don't!